# Django reverse() in get_absolute_url() doesn't work

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to use the reverse function in get_absolute_url() and it is not finding the correct reverse match for the view. My url.py doesn't have any errors because I can access that view through the url "traildetail/4" etc and all the other urls are working fine.

I have a following **view** function:

```
def get_trail_detail(request, trail_id=None):
    '''
    '''
    return HttpResponse(str(trail_id))
```

I also have the following url defined in **urls.py**.

```
url(r'^traildetail/(?P<trail_id>\d{1,5})/$', 'get_trail_detail', name='get-trail-detail'),
```

So when I run the following code in the **django shell** I get the NoReverseMatch error:

```
reverse('trails.views.get_trail_detail',None, kwargs={'trail_id': '3'})
reverse('trails.views.get_trail_detail', args=[str(1)])
reverse('trails.views.get_trail_detail', kwargs={'trail_id': '3'})
```

I get the following **Error:** for all of the above attempts:

```
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 416, in _reverse_with_prefix
    "arguments '%s' not found." % (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'trails.views.get_trail_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'trail_id': '3'}' not found
    enter code here
```

Comment: did you try `reverse('get-trail-detail', kwargs={'trail_id': 3})`

Comment: Yes. I get the same error with that one.

Comment: You need to pass `trail_id` argument as an integer, rather than a string.

    `reverse('get-trail-detail', kwargs={'trail_id': 3})` #do not use the quotes.

Comment: I tried with both, string and integer, and they both toss the same error.

Comment: It actually does pick up the correct url (**traildetail/**) when I look at the stack trace, however it doesn't pick up the arguments that I am passing.

Comment: This should have worked - alteast the named url approach - `reverse("get-trail-detail", kwargs=dict(trail_id=3))`

Comment: It worked. I tried again with the `kwargs` as an int this time in the actual get_absolute_url function. I don't know why the same thing is not working in the django shell. **Weird**

Comment: Seems like @karhikr first answer should work.  You should include what version of Django you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference - You can access the url like this:

```
reverse('get-trail-detail', kwargs={'trail_id': 3})
```